# Draw Line Connecting Ends of 2 Parallel Lines with AutoLisp

Tags: parallel-processing, line, autocad, autolisp

does anyone have an AutoLisp routine to quickly draw a line connecting two parallel lines. I would really like something that works similar to the fillet command, except drawing a straight line instead of a radius. This could almost be accomplished with the chamfer command, except chamfer does not work with parallel lines.

My job sometimes consists of offsetting a lot of pairs of parallel lines and then connecting them with another line to create rectangles. It is easy enough to just draw a line between them, but it is still a tedious process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun c:connectLines (/ line1 line2 data1 data2 pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4)
  (and
    (setq line1 (car (entsel "\nSelect first line: ")))
    (= (cdr (assoc 0 (setq data1 (entget line1)))) "LINE")
    (setq line2 (car (entsel "\nSelect second line: ")))
    (= (cdr (assoc 0 (setq data2 (entget line2)))) "LINE")
    (setq pt1 (cdr (assoc 10 data1))
          pt2 (cdr (assoc 11 data1))
          pt3 (cdr (assoc 11 data2))
          pt4 (cdr (assoc 10 data2))
    )
    (or (< (distance pt2 pt3) (distance pt2 pt4))
        (mapcar 'set '(pt3 pt4) (list pt4 pt3))
    )
    (command "_.erase"
             (ssadd line2 (ssadd line1))
             ""
             "_.pline"
             "_non"
             (trans pt1 0 1)
             "_non"
             (trans pt2 0 1)
             "_non"
             (trans pt3 0 1)
             "_non"
             (trans pt4 0 1)
             "_close"
    )
  )
  (princ)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful!